# PowerShell Set-PhysicalDisk when there are identical FriendlyName's

Tags: powershell

I ran `Get-PhysicalDisk` inside a  virtual machine which has 4 hard disks. The result was:

```
FriendlyName             SerialNumber CanPool OperationalStatus HealthStatus Usage         Size
------------             ------------ ------- ----------------- ------------ -----         ----
VMware, VMware Virtual S              False   OK                Healthy      Auto-Select  60 GB
VMware, VMware Virtual S              False   OK                Healthy      Auto-Select 100 GB
VMware, VMware Virtual S              False   OK                Healthy      Auto-Select 200 GB
VMware, VMware Virtual S              False   OK                Healthy      Auto-Select 400 GB
```

There were no SerialNumber's or any other unique ID that I could see in the result above.

Now, I need to run `Set-PhysicalDisk`. All examples on the web use the unique FriendlyName or something like `PhysicalDisk1`. First, there are 4 disks with the same FriendlyName's, so I think I cannot use it. Secondly, I thought `PhysicalDisk{number}` was a special name to point a disk by the index, but it did not seem to work.

What should I pass to `Set-PhysicalDisk`, if I want to designate, say, the second disk above (size = 100GB)?

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Set-PhysicalDisk -FriendlyName "VMware, VMware Virtual S" -Usage Retired
Set-PhysicalDisk : Not Supported
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-PhysicalDisk -FriendlyName "VMware, VMware Virtual S" -Usage Reti ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (StorageWMI:ROOT/Microsoft/..._StorageCmdlets) [Set-PhysicalDisk], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StorageWMI 1,Set-PhysicalDisk

PS C:\Users\Administrator> Set-PhysicalDisk PhysicalDisk1 -Usage Retired
Set-PhysicalDisk : The requested object could not be found.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-PhysicalDisk PhysicalDisk1 -Usage Retired
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (PS_StorageCmdlets:ROOT/Microsoft/..._StorageCmdlets) [Set-PhysicalDisk], CimException
```

Comment: Have you checked the `UniqueID` of each disk? Try `Get-PhysicalDisk | Select-Object SerialNumber,UniqueID`. You should be able to `Set-PhysicalDisk` by `UniqueID` instead of the `FriendlyName`.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I tried to find a way to retrieve the UniqueIDs by the Get-PhysicalDisk command, but the manual page only showed how to get only the disk of matching UniqueID. I think it needs some background knowledge of PowerShell to figure out Select-Object. For anyone who have the same problem, I passed the UniqueID like `-Set-PhysicalDisk -UniqueId "{7a1... lonng hex... }"`

Comment: Any of the properties you find in `Get-Help` for a cmdlet (eg Get-Help Get-PhysicalDisk -full) can be returned with Select-Object

Answer (score 4):

You can `Set-PhysicalDisk` by using the `UniqueID`.

To retrieve the `UniqueID`,

```
Get-PhysicalDisk | Select-Object SerialNumber,UniqueID
```

To make updates based on the `UniqueID`,

```
Set-PhysicalDisk -UniqueId "{<insert_UniqueID>}"
```

Comment: Be warned that **UniqueId** [isn't unique.](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/578a4c17-ed61-4d1a-837b-bdde46f2e7fe/storage-spaces-ui-missing-disks-when-a-controller-reports-the-same-uniqueid-for-all-attached-disks?forum=winserver8gen)

Answer (score 4):

You can assign that disk *"object"* to a variable. With that variable you can perform the operations on the variable itself - all without even needing a **FriendlyName** or **SerialNumber**

### Details

In my case i had **no** `FriendlyName`, nor any `SerialNumber`:

```
FriendlyName   CanPool  OperationalStatus   HealthStatus  Usage             Size
------------   -------  -----------------   ------------  -----             ----
PhysicalDisk1  False    OK                  Healthy       Auto-Select    1.82 TB
PhysicalDisk3  False    OK                  Healthy       Auto-Select    1.82 TB
PhysicalDisk4  False    OK                  Healthy       Auto-Select    1.82 TB
PhysicalDisk0  False    OK                  Healthy       Auto-Select  111.79 GB
PhysicalDisk8  False    OK                  Healthy       Auto-Select    1.82 TB
PhysicalDisk2  False    OK                  Healthy       Auto-Select  465.76 GB
               False    Lost Communication  Warning       Retired      930.75 GB
PhysicalDisk6  False    OK                  Healthy       Auto-Select  930.75 GB
PhysicalDisk9  False    OK                  Healthy       Auto-Select  930.75 GB
PhysicalDisk7  False    OK                  Healthy       Auto-Select    1.82 TB
PhysicalDisk5  False    OK                  Healthy       Auto-Select    1.82 TB
```

The easiest thing i could key on was that the **OperationalStatus** said `Lost Communication`:

```
#Single out the disk that has lost communication
Get-PhysicalDisk | Where-Object { $_.OperationalStatus -eq 'Lost Communication' }
```

From there i can assign that disk to a variable:

```
#Assign the missing disk to a variable
$missingDisk = Get-PhysicalDisk | Where-Object { $_.OperationalStatus -eq 'Lost Communication' }
```

Now that i have a variable object, i can mark that disk as retired:

```
#tell the storage pool that the disk has been retired:
$missingDisk | Set-PhysicalDisk -Usage Retired
```

And then to top it off, repair all volumes on the storage space that were affected:

```
# To Repair all Warning Volumes
Get-VirtualDisk | Where-Object –FilterScript {$_.HealthStatus –Eq 'Warning'} | Repair-VirtualDisk
```

You can confirm that a virtual disk is being repaired by seeing that its **OperationStatus** is `InService`:

```
#Disks will show as `InService` to let us know that they're currently being repaired
Get-VirtualDisks

FriendlyName      ResiliencySettingName  OperationalStatus  HealthStatus  IsManualAttach   Size
------------      ---------------------  -----------------  ------------  --------------   ----
Three-way mirror  Mirror                 InService          Warning       False           10 TB
PooledParityDisk  Parity                 InService          Warning       False           15 TB
```

And finally you can monitor the progress of the repair:

```
#Monitor the percentage of the repair
Get-StorageJob

Name          ElapsedTime  JobState  PercentComplete  IsBackgroundTask
----          -----------  --------  ---------------  ----------------
Regeneration  00:00:00     Running   40               True
Regeneration  00:00:00     New       0                True
```

Thanks to [Matthew Hodgkins](https://hodgkins.io/replace-failed-disk-in-storage-spaces-pool-with-powershell). *([archive](http://archive.is/nZJtW))*

*p.s.* the person thinking PowerShell is a good idea should be shot

Answer (score 0):

When I run into this issue, I turn to Select-Object (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7)

This isn't terribly elegant, but if you can list your objects and know you want only specific ones, you can array index them with Select-Object.

i.e. if you want to operate on the third hard drive:

> Get-PhysicalDisk | Select-Object -Index 2 | Set-PhysicalDisk...