# Friendly name set using set-physicaldisk is reset after reboot

Tags: windows, powershell

I've set a scsi disk's friendly name using set-physicaldisk however I've found that rebooting the machine causes the friendly name to be removed and reset to the original value.

Is there a way of persisting that friendly name? Or has anyone seen this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: No I'm not. In fact it seems to happen in different envs (home and work computers)

Comment: Cee here in case it helps: https://superuser.com/questions/1129089/powershell-set-physicaldisk-when-there-are-identical-friendlynames, but what is the exact command(s) you are running? I see `Reset-PhysicalDisk` has a `-FreindlyName` but that sounds a little dangerous for just friendly name updates but I do not have a test environment at the moment to test, it you do, play with that and reboot and see what happens, and what else that may mean in case it destroys your configuration entirely.

Comment: I'm use `set-physicaldisk`. So an example would be `set-physicaldisk -UniqueId myUniqueId -NewFriendlyName myFriendlyName`. This sets the friendly name fine. However if I reboot the machine then the friendly name is reverted back to the original value.

Comment: As per here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/reset-physicaldisk?view=windowsserver2022-ps, what about trying with `Reset-PhysicalDisk -FriendlyName "PhysicalDisk5"` as mentioned. I also wasn't sure if this metadata that talks about may be the issue if you're able to test with caution of course: https://i.imgur.com/h9IOIwQ.png